# How do I make the text in a textarea monospace when using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following `textarea` element:

```
<form action="/checkit" method="get">
    <textarea class="field span8" id="textarea" name="user_input" 
        rows="20">{{default_data}}</textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Checker">
</form>
```

I have just started using `bootstrap`, but can't work out the best way to make the text in the textarea monospace.

Comment: Using CSS `textarea {font-family:"Monospace";}` if it isn't working then make sure there's no other CSS rule that's overriding it, else use the `!important` in the value, use it with care.

Comment: I don't want to have text monospace in all textareas, just one.

Comment: @DeepakKamat, the quotes are wrong, unless you expect a system to have a font with the specific name Monospace.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Adding the following to your textarea tag should work

```
 style="font-family:monospace;"
```

or else you can just add it to your css like this

```
#textarea{font-family:monospace;}
```

Comment: that worked except needed to use style="font-family:Monospace;" as per the comments above.

Comment: @smithy, glad I could help.  someone downvoted me :/ It might not be the best fix since you're supposed to separate your code from the styling but it works. Maybe making a class something like "textareamono" and applying that would be a better idea in the long run.

Comment: you made a mistake mono-space should be monospace, i've made an edit to your post and upvoted it

Answer (score 14):

Twitter Bootstrap sets many styling features, and it is not always trivial to override them. For a specific element, though, it is easy when using a fairly specific selector like an id selector. In your case, the `textarea` element has `id="textarea"`, so you can use e.g.

```
<style>
#textarea { font-family: Consolas, Lucida Console, monospace; }
</style>
```

You can list any sequence of monospace fonts in order of preference, but make the last entry `monospace` (without quotations marks) last, because it means falling back to the browser’s default monospace font.

It is normally not good for usability to set font to monospace in `textarea`, unless perhaps the expected input is computer code, rows of numbers, or other text that is suitable for monospace rendering.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the most comprehensive answer, thus, the best one.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Bootstrap 4, use "text-monospace" class:

```
<textarea class="field span8 text-monospace" id="textarea" name="user_input" rows="20">
  {{default_data}}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap we have styles:

```
input,
button,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

In your css you need to change this into:

```
#textarea { 
font-family: monospace; 
}
```

So with id your textarea will have higher priority.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `font-monospace` to the textarea class.

```
<form action="/checkit" method="get">
    <textarea class="field span8 font-monospace" id="textarea" name="user_input" 
        rows="20">{{default_data}}</textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Checker">
</form>
```

In Bootstrap v5.0 there is a breaking change.

**Breaking** Renamed `.text-monospace` to `.font-monospace`.

Change noted here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities

**Monospace font in Bootstrap v5.0**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#monospace